# Highlighting svg element

Tags: css, svg

I have a task to make illumination svg element when you hover the mouse cursor over it. The problem is that the styles of custom elements should not be changed. A light should appear on the sides of the element.

In part I understand that the problem can be solved by using svg filters. Only here can be on top of the element is another element of translucent light and the first to be partially attenuated (so to speak).

Please give advice

Comment: I have no experience with SVG but is it viable to change the SVG on hover and put another SVG with the "glow" around it? Again as i said i don't know if this a proper solution maybe there is another more elegant approach.

Comment: Such a method is right for me. As I said it is being implemented through the filters. But what about the second problem? Above the element can be located and translucent element glow nor should disappear.

Comment: Have you seen an example somewhere else ? I'm not quite sure from your question if you are trying to figure out how to do illumination or if you have some and you just want to incorporate it into the svg. Maybe show the bits you have so far and we can take a look.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you attach a screen shot of before and after of what you're aiming for? Or a code sample?

Comment: Is this similar to what you are looking for? I add a rectangle on top of element.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXhS2KwPXGo